# Save(serialize?) web page data from WebView

Tags: java, javascript, android

I've got WebView, which runs JS/html code. I need to be able to save JS code state with all variables so that I can restore it later.
I know about localStorage api, but I need to save the whole web page state. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a control over the JavaScript code on the page?

I would inject a custom JS function via [WebView.addJavascriptInterface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String%29).

Something like 'backupData(data)' where data is an object holding all the data I want to preserve. Then I would add a call to this function to the Javascript code of the page.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use browser cookies to save you javascript variables? If you need to save this information on the server side, you'll probably need to use AJAX + some server side code.